# Facebook Stream Publish Issue: Modal stuck "loading..."

Tags: javascript, facebook

I have been experiencing intermittent issues with facebook stream publishes. When a stream publish is called, the modal placeholder pops up with "Loading..." but often never loads. Since the issue comes and goes, I had always assumed facebook itself was the problem. There is no modal error message as would be expected if an invalid parameter were passed in and I don't see any failed requests or javascript errors. I don't really have any clues as to what is causing this, we just know it leads to a painfully high percentage of lost publishes.

My colleague suggests chrome is failing more consistently than other browsers, but I have seen this in every browser environment.

The code in question is in an iframe on an FBML canvas, I'm using the current and latest JS SDK. The following JS libs are in use:

Google analytics

Facebook SDK

swfobject

Jquery 1.4.2

Jquery dump plugin

facebox

ba-debug

Here's my wrapper for all the stream publishes the app generates:

```
function streamPublish(name, caption, description, icon, href, actiontext, message, recipient, properties) {
      var attachment =  {
        'media':[{'type':'image','src':icon,'href': href}],
        'name': name,
        'caption': caption,     
        'description': description,
        'href': href
      };
      if (properties !== undefined && properties !== ''){
        attachment.properties = properties;
      }
      if (recipient === undefined || recipient === ''){
        recipient = getUserId();
      }
      FB.ui({
        method: 'stream.publish',
        'message': message,
        attachment: attachment,
        action_links: [{'text':actiontext, 'href':href}],
        target_id:recipient 
      },
      function(response) {
        if (response && response.post_id) {
          publishSuccess(response);
        } else {
          publishFail();
        }
      });
    }
```

This has been hurting the app for a while, any help clues would be much appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at network requests in firebug, see if there are any timeouts. Did facebook api initialize successfully when this happens? Can you perform other successful requests to facebook when this error happens?

Comment: Actually, I did dig a little deeper and took a look at how the SDK renders the stream publish modals. It looks like the there are 2 modals, one with the "Loading..." indicator and one with an iframe that loads the publisher at this url: http://www.facebook.com/connect/prompt_feed.php

I was able to reproduce the issue, and sure enough the iframe-modal is sitting 10000 pixels off of the page, fully loaded, waiting to be moved in. There must be some event that fires when the iframe has finished loading that tells the SDK to move the modal into place. Whatever this mechanism is, fails frequently.

Comment: Between my web proxy and firebug, I cannot see any difference between the requests/responses of a successful publish attempt and a fail.

I am pretty sure the api is initializing properly, or else we wouldn't even be seeing the "loading" modal as it is contained within the markup generated by the SDK. Also, all the auth tokens and such are fine. 

I am tempted to write my own iframe modal wrapper and just load up prompt_feed.php with all of the parameters passed in the query string - but thats probably a big waste of time.

Comment: I created a thread on the facebook developer forum here: http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?pid=261115#p261115

Comment: Update: I'm going to try adding the "display" parameter to FB.ui and test for a few days to see if that makes a difference. Looking at the SDK source, lack of session will force "popup" mode instead of "iframe" or "dialog". Not sure exactly what each does yet.





     // cannot use an iframe "dialog" if a session is not available
    if (!FB._session && params.display == 'dialog' && !method.loggedOutIframe) {
      FB.log('"dialog" mode can only be used when the user is connected.');
      params.display = 'popup';
    }

Answer (score 1):

Facebook knows about the bug. It has like 2500 votes
in their bug tracker.

Awesome.

http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=10180

http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?pid=262043#p262043

http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=60357

http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=60382

http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=57404

http://github.com/facebook/connect-js/issues/#issue/65

http://github.com/facebook/connect-js/issues/#issue/72

Comment: classic... for a company of this size and scope... they really are on par with Microsoft when it comes to producing crap that is either completely retarded in regards to user-guidance, or just doesn't work properly (or at all for that matter).
The perks of being massive... you can just not care because .... well... what are we gonna do?

Comment: I still see this sort of hung modal issue all the time.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem could be during the authentication between client and server, because every other stream.publish call works except for the first.

Try setting 'cookie' to false in FB.init... I reasoned that might force the init to actually contact the server

```
FB.init({

...

cookie:  false,

...

});
```

Haven't thoroughly tested it, but it seems it might just work.

UPDATE: unfortunately, it seems it won't fix it for all the cases

Comment: there is yet another tread about this issue:
http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?pid=239419